Is the Forgers Of Marbled City's Family move supposed to be Crop Rotation or Delving The Depths
I have been invited to play a game of 'Free from the yoke' so I was reviewing the book and I was thinking of selecting the 'Forgers Of Marbled City' In the book it has a move called 'Crop Rotation' which reads as:

When you start a massive crop planting operation, erase an
appropriate surplus. At the start of the next season, gain Surplus:
Crops or Surplus: Raw Materials. At the start of the season after
that, gain whichever surplus you didn’t pick

Whereas in the playbooks provided by UFOPRESS they instead have 'Delving The Depths'

When you start a new mining operation, erase an appropriate surplus. At
the start of the next season, gain Surplus: Coin or Surplus: Raw Materials. At
the start of the season after that, gain whichever surplus you didn’t pick

Which one of the moves is the correct version?

I wonder: what would you think of tagging this question with [tag:powered-by-the-apocalypse]? It's not explicitly PbtA, but reading through the Legacy SRD it does acknowledge inspiration from AW and hoo-boy does it read like PbtA.

That does make sense since people familiar with PbtA are likely to be familiar with LAtR. I'll do that. Thank you.

Unless your GM insists on it, use the handout as provided.
I've reached out to the original author about this (through a private backchannel) and they couldn't remember which one was supposed to be final, but there are several good arguments in favor of the handout's version.

You're the house who decides where the mountain range goes and you can decorate it with mysterious metals and unusual fires. Mining is way more in your wheelhouse than farming is.

The handout's marginally easier to use as printed, as compared to stickering a correction over the top, but if someone's determined that's not really a big concern.

Mechanically (that is, divorced from story), one has no advantage over the other, in that you're giving up one surplus now to get two in installments no matter which version you're using. Neither Crops nor Coin are called out as being specially required by any Arbiter projects, so the only worth of one over the other is what you can make of it in the moment.

One of the payouts of a successful Arbiter project (for two out of the three Arbiters, anyway) is giving every House involved a Crops surplus. You can't really get the same one twice, and while there's plenty of room for you to try and leverage one surplus to get another, why make that a concern when you don't have to?


Though by the same token, Crop Rotation isn't too powerful a starting move for any house to have, either, so if somebody (not even you, necessarily) really wants their house to have a farming trick, it's also up for grabs.
